# python store array slices a[n:m] b[n:m]

Tags: python, arrays

How can I store where I will slice if I have multiple arrays?

Instead of having this:

```
a1[5:8]
a2[5:8]
b1[5:8]
```

I have:

```
slicePart = [5:8]

a1[slicePart]
a2[slicePart]
b1[slicePart]
```

Comment: I don't know if I fully understand your question but you could use variable:

`start = 5
end = 8
a1[start:end]`

Comment: you can store 5 and 8 independently, like `start=5, end=8, a1[start:end]`

Comment: `slice()` is intself a function, check it out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The slicing syntax is simply syntactic sugar for passing a `slice` object. So you can use:

```
slicepart = slice(5, 8)
```

So, you can play around with:

```
In [21]: class MyObj:
    ...:     def __getitem__(self, item):
    ...:         print(item)
    ...:

In [22]: obj = MyObj()

In [23]: obj[5]
5

In [24]: obj[5:8]
slice(5, 8, None)

In [25]: obj[5, 8]
(5, 8)
```